# Technical consultation questions related to Google login

Tags: android, react-google-login

What happens if I don’t adjust the signOut method after I log in with Google, because I encountered a problem reported by users. When users call Google to log in, they fail to get getSignedInAccountFromIntent. The specific reason for the failure is not clear, but I suspect it is It's not because I didn't call the signOut method. I want to ask you for help.

The main reason is that everything is normal on my side, but users have reported this problem, so I would like to ask if anyone has encountered this problem, the above is just my guess